# RxJS: deferred inner-observables still run even when the outer-observable has no subscription left

Tags: rxjs

I just realized that inner-observables (like those defined in a mergeMap or switchMap operator) do not "stop" even when the outer-observable has no subscription left.

For a better example, let's show some code:

```
const {
  Subject,
  of: obsOf,
  concat: obsConcat,
  defer,
} = require("rxjs");
const {
  finalize,
  mergeMap,
  tap,
  takeUntil,
} = require("rxjs/operators");

const subject = new Subject();

obsOf(null).pipe(
  mergeMap(() =>
    obsConcat(
      defer(() => {
        console.log("side-effect 1");
        return obsOf(1);
      }),
      defer(() => {
        console.log("side-effect 2");
        return obsOf(2);
      }),
      defer(() => {
        console.log("side-effect 3");
        return obsOf(3);
      })
    )
  ),
  finalize(() => {
    console.log("finalized");
  })
)
.pipe(
  takeUntil(subject),
  tap((i) => {
    if (i === 2) {
      subject.next();
    }
  })
).subscribe(
  (i) => { console.log("next", i); },
  (e) => { console.log("error", e); },
  () => { console.log("complete"); },
);

// Ouput:
// > side-effect 1
// > next 1
// > side-effect 2
// > complete
// > finalized
// > side-effect 3
```

The fact that the `side-effect 3` line is logged is weird since the outer observable already called `finalize`.

As all those side-effects are in a `defer`, they could perfectly be avoided after unsubscription. From my point-of-view, those side-effects provide no value at all.

Any idea why RxJS still execute those ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately by design (as of RxJS 6) - `concat` will buffer the observables and will subscribe to each buffered one even after you unsubscribe (if the subscription is `closed` it will subscribe and immediately unsubscribe).

You have to prevent the observables from getting buffered...

```
obsOf(null).pipe(
  mergeMap(() => obsOf(
    defer(() => {
      console.log("side-effect 1");
      return obsOf(1);
    }),
    defer(() => {
      console.log("side-effect 2");
      return obsOf(2);
    }),
    defer(() => {
      console.log("side-effect 3");
      return obsOf(3);
    })
  )),
  concatAll(),
  finalize(() => {
    console.log("finalized");
  }),
  takeUntil(subject),
  tap((i) => {
    if (i === 2) {
      subject.next();
    }
  })
).subscribe(
  (i) => { console.log("next", i); },
  (e) => { console.log("error", e); },
  () => { console.log("complete"); },
);
```

One could think the code above works, but only until you delay one of the observables. Replace `obsOf(1)` with `timer(100).pipe(mapTo(1));` and behavior is exactly the same.

The only workaround is to make sure you are not buffering anything (mean don't use `concat*` operators) or limit observable production some other way (use separate Subject and control the production manually).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Any idea why they changed the design of concat in RxJS6?
Running Observables lazily, even concatenated ones, seems much more Rx-like.